# How to retrieve a specific Member from a Discord Guild using Java JDA

Tags: java, discord-jda

I am trying to get a specific Member object from a Guild by using the following:
`event.getGuild().getMember(user)`
Here, user is the User object of the user I want to get the Member object from. I have also tried using the .getMemberById, using the userID instead. However, in both cases I get a null-pointer exception.

I am sure that both my User object and userID are correct, because when adding a breakpoint it does show these, but it doesn't retrieve the Member, this stays null. Am I approaching this wrong?

I have also tried putting the following in my main file where I start the bot:

```
JDABuilder builder = JDABuilder.createDefault(BOT_TOKEN);
builder.enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS);
```

On the Discord developer portal I have enabled both the 'Privileged Gateway Intents' options.

Comment: Can you post the entire NP exception?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation of Guild#getMember](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#getMember(net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.User)) tells you to **see also** [Guild#retrieveMember](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#retrieveMember(net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.User)) which can be used to load members that are not cached.

If you have an event with a `getMember()` or `retrieveMember()` method, that should be used instead. Otherwise you can do this:

```java
guild.retrieveMember(user).queue(member -> {
  ... use member here
});
```

Other alternatives are outlined in the JDA wiki here: [Gateway Intents and Member Cache Policy](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/Gateway-Intents-and-Member-Cache-Policy#loading-members)

Most of these retrieval methods **DO NOT** require the privileged intent `GUILD_MEMBERS`. It is only required if you want to interact with the entire member list of a server, through methods like `loadMembers` or `findMembers` for example.